# Ubuntu OS hanged stage

Tags: 12.04, webapps

I am using ubuntu and some times it is going to hanged stage while running 2 or more webapps simultaneously. Is there any way similar Alt+Ctrl+Delete to Task manager in Windows for sudden terminations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your screen freezes completely you can do `crtl + alt + f2` to get a terminal.
From there you can use `top` which will display running proccesses. Press k and then enter the PID of the process you want to kill.
Or you can use `ps aux | grep proccesYouWantToKill` to get the PID and then `kill -9 PID` to terminate the process.
`crtl + alt + f1 - f6` are comand line only `crtl + alt + f7` will bring you back to your desktop.

Comment: full screen will be hanged.

Comment: Then try what I have mentioned above. If you don't get a TTY with `crtl + alt + f2` your complete computer crashed and you have to restart manually.

Comment: i am getting a new terminal, but after killing the job by grep command, how can i exit from that terminal.?? Again I have done reboot command. Which is the proper command for exit?

Comment: `crtl + alt + f7` will bring you back to your desktop.

Comment: yaa its works fine... thanqq...

Comment: Also `kill -9 -1` is useful if wanted to kill all process and this will back to login screen!